# ArrayList<>, adding Objects on creation of another Object

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist, constructor

I'm trying to add a series of one Object to another Object in an ArrayList.
In this case, I have "Task", which is a series of Object type "SubTask". Whenever the user presses a specific button, it should add another SubTask to the Task. I have a few issues with doing this in the constructor, and generally transferring the ArrayList of SubTask to Task. The calculations of min time and max time I can probably figure out myself.

```
 public class Task {
    //our Task has a name, a number of SubTasks, cues and two calculated times (min and max)
    public String TaskName;
    public int calculatedMaxTime; public int calculatedMinTime; public int subtasks;
    public boolean cueEt; public boolean cueTo;

    //it has an ArrayList of SubTasks
    ArrayList<SubTask> myList = new ArrayList<SubTask>();

    //lets make a task
    public Task(String setName, int calcTimeMin,int calcTimeMax,
                  int calcSubs, boolean setCueOne, boolean setCueTwo) {

        //calcTimeMin = myList.
        //calcTimeMax =
        //we need to add subtasks in the constructor somehow
        //we need these subtasks to be specific to the task

        TaskName = setName;
        //set the Task's variables
        calculatedMaxTime = calcTimeMax; calculatedMinTime = calcTimeMin; subtasks = calcSubs;
        cueEt = setCueOne; cueTo = setCueTwo;
    }

}

public class SubTask {
    //vores underopgavbe har et navn, en minimum og en max tid
    String Name;
    int minTime; int maxTime;

    public SubTask(String setSubName, int setMinTime, int setMaxTime) {
        Name = setSubName;
        minTime = setMinTime; maxTime = setMaxTime;
    }
}
```

Please forgive the Danish words here and there, I haven't cleaned my code yet.

**EDIT (question if you can't see it):** How do I add (user-defined) SubTasks to the Task users are creating? Do I use the constructor or define a method for it?

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: Where do you get the list of `SubTask`:s in the constructor? It seems like you want to populate `myList` with nothing to populate it with. Perhaps give a list of `SubTask`:s as an argument to the constructor?

Comment: You mean something like `myList.add(new SubTask(subname,minTime,maxTime));` ?

Comment: I guess your class `Task` is missing a method like `addSubTask()`?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to pass the subtasks into the task array. The most obvious is to add an `addSubTask(Subtask)` method to the Task class, and then invoke that in whatever code creates the task.

In main code

```
Task task = new Task(args...); //put real args in actual code
//do stuff

public void onButtonPress(){
    SubTask subtask = new SubTask(args...); //put real args in actual code
    task.addSubTask(subtask);
}
```

In Task

```
public class Task{

    //already existing code

    public void addSubTask(SubTask subtask){
        myList.add(subtask);
    }

}
```

Alternatively you could add an `ArrayList<SubTask>` object to the Task constructor's arguments, which would let you pass in a whole bunch of sub-tasks at once - albeit without the ability to add new ones once the Task is constructed. This might be combined with the prior solution to allow you to add SubTasks after the object's creation is over.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way:

```
 ArrayList<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<Task>(); 

 Task task = new Task(...);
 SubTask subtask1 = new SubTask(...);
 task.myList.add(subtask1);
 SubTask subtask2 = new SubTask(...);
 task.myList.add(subtask2);
 SubTask subtask3 = new SubTask(...);
 task.myList.add(subtask3);
        ...
        ...

 taskList.add(task);
```